# How to add pattern based dependency

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to add a common dependency to multiple files.  I have attempted this via pattern matching but I can't get it to work.  Below is my minimally re-producible example:

```
file1.out:
    cat source.txt | grep "hello,world" > file1.out

file2.out:
   cat source.txt > file2.out

%.out: source.txt
```

My goal is to add source.txt as a dependency to file1.out and file2.out (as well as every other *.out file that I may add later on).  Any advice would be appreciated (apologies if this is a basic question but I couldn't find anything related in the make manuals.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "I can't get it to work".

Comment: As in the above code doesn't work in the way I expected/wanted it to.  I tried using wildcard variables instead such as  `OUTFILES = $(wildcard *.out) ; $(OUTFILES): source.txt`  which semi works but doesn't work in the case where files come from sub directories.

Comment: Can people please clarify why my question is getting down voted so I can improve it and learn how to write better questions for next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using GNU make. Your problem comes from how pattern (implicit) rules are handled by GNU make. From the introduction of section [Implicit Rule Search Algorithm](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rule-Search) of the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html):

> Here is the procedure make uses for searching for an implicit rule for
>   a target t. This procedure is followed for each double-colon rule with
>   no recipe, for each target of ordinary rules none of which have a
>   recipe, and for each prerequisite that is not the target of any rule.
>   It is also followed recursively for prerequisites that come from
>   implicit rules, in the search for a chain of rules.

So, your pattern rule is not considered for `file1.out` and `file2.out` targets because they are targets of ordinary rules **with a recipe**.

Solution: you could list the `*.out` targets in a variable and use it to declare that they all depend on `source.txt`:

```
OUTFILES := $(wildcard *.out)

$(OUTFILES): source.txt

file1.out:
    cat source.txt | grep "hello,world" > file1.out

file2.out:
    cat source.txt > file2.out
```

In case the targets can be in subdirectories, you can use the `shell`make function to call `find`, instead of using the `wildcard` make function:

```
OUTFILES := $(shell find . -type f -name '*.out')
```

Notes:

1. This will work only for existing `*.out` files. Make cannot invent the list of target files if they don't exist already (and can thus be searched by make) and if you don't provide the list yourself in the makefile.
2. Your `cat source.txt | grep "hello,world" > file1.out` recipe will fail with a non-zero exit status if the `source.txt` file does not contain the `hello,world`string. And if this happens make will terminate with an error message. You can avoid this with:

   ```
   cat source.txt | grep "hello,world" > file1.out || true
   ```
3. Automatic variables can be really handy. If `source.txt` is the only prerequisite of your targets you could simplify all this with recipes like:

   ```
   file1.out:
       cat "$<" | grep "hello,world" > "$@" || true

   file2.out:
       cat "$<" > "$@"
   ```

   (`$@` expands as the target of the rule and `$<` expands as the first prerequisite). This avoids typos and makes the recipes more generic. Sometimes you can even have the same recipe for several targets:

   ```
   file1.out file3.out:
       cat "$<" | grep "hello,world" > "$@" || true
   ```